# Fetching files from Jersey using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, character-encoding

I've got a webservice with which the user can download a file (docx or pdf file). This piece of code represents it:

```
@GET
@Path("explicacionOperador/explicacion_operador_ticket_{id_ticket}.pdf")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response generarDocumentoExplicacionOperadorPostPdf(
    @PathParam("id_ticket") String pTicketId,
    @HeaderParam("nombre_apellidos") String nombre_apellidos,
    @HeaderParam("domicilio") String domicilio,
    @HeaderParam("codigo_postal") String codigo_postal,
    @HeaderParam("localidad") String localidad,
    @HeaderParam("provincia") String provincia,
    @HeaderParam("linea") String linea,
    @HeaderParam("operador") String operador,
    @HeaderParam("mensaje") String mensaje
) throws IOException, ConfigurationException, URISyntaxException, FormatoNoSoportadoException{
    ETipoDocumento tipo = FormatoNoSoportadoException.testFormato("pdf");
    File documentoExplicacionOperador = this.generalService.getDocumentoExplicacionOperador(
            tipo, 
            pTicketId, 
            nombre_apellidos, 
            domicilio, 
            codigo_postal, 
            localidad, 
            provincia, 
            linea, 
            operador, 
            mensaje);
    return Response
            .ok(documentoExplicacionOperador, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + documentoExplicacionOperador.getName() + "\"" )
            .header("Charset", "ISO-8859-1")
            .build();
}
```

On the other side, I've got a client written in plain HTML+JS, using jQuery 3 raw ajax calls like this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

            $("#dale").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var tgt = "resources/documentos/explicacionOperador/explicacion_operador_ticket_666.docx";
                $.ajax({
                    url: tgt,
                    type: 'GET',
                    //mimeType: "application/octet-stream",
                    //contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1',
                    //async: true,
                    processData: false,
                    success: //download.bind(true, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "explicacion_operador_ticket_666.docx"),
                        function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                    error: function(data){
                        var elError = "Error al hacer la llamada a " + tgt + ": " + data;
                        console.log(elError);
                        console.log(data);
                        alert(elError);
                    },
                    headers: {
                        nombre_apellidos: "Mike Poborsky",
                        domicilio: "St. Mary 4",
                        codigo_postal: "194",
                        localidad: "Julapa",
                        provincia: "Asada",
                        linea: "SB64533",
                        operador: "Julandrin",
                        mensaje: "Recarga no funciona"
                    }/*,
                    scriptCharset: "ISO-8859-1"*/
                });
            });
            ...
```

When executing it, a message like this gets printed within the console:
[image: characters]

When I comment out the code lines related to the encoding, nothing changes. Obviously, when I serve the file to download, the file is corrupted (the file is 25KB when it's actually 17KB).

I've tried it in Soap UI and, not knowing why, I get a different output:
[image: soap ui response]

My question is am I doing something wrong in my ajax call? The data I get seems to be binary, but I don't know why it's different in the browser comparing to Soap UI.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself. Due to the delay, I looked for other ways to implement the Ajax request, so I decided to make use of raw XMLHttpRequest... And it worked! To download the file, I've used [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) library.

Simply as follows:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", tgt, true);
oReq.setRequestHeader("nombre_apellidos", "Mike Poborsky");
oReq.setRequestHeader("domicilio", "St. Mary 4");
oReq.setRequestHeader("codigo_postal", "123");
oReq.setRequestHeader("localidad", "Julapa");
oReq.setRequestHeader("provincia", "Asada");
oReq.setRequestHeader("linea", "SBD0345");
oReq.setRequestHeader("operador", "Yay");
oReq.setRequestHeader("mensaje", "Recarga no funciona");
oReq.responseType = "blob";
oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    download(oReq.response, "explicacion_operador_ticket_666.docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
};
oReq.send();
```